# Failed to download asset opsworks-ruby2.1 for Install user space OpsWorks ruby package

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, vagrant, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I have an error when I'm running "vagrant provision":

```
nisevi@localhost processor (master):$ vagrant provision
Using ssh deploy key of: /home/nisevi/.ssh/id_rsa
==> default: Chef 11.10.0 Omnibus package is already installed.
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: W
==> default: : 
==> default: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages)
==> default: W
==> default: : 
==> default: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages)
==> default: W
==> default: : 
==> default: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages)
==> default: W
==> default: : 
==> default: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages)
==> default: 
==> default: W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages)
==> default: W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages)
==> default: W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
==> default: Detected Chef (latest) is already installed
Generating chef JSON and uploading...
==> default: Running chef-solo...
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:32+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:32+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.10.0 ***
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:32+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 1366
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:43+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["role[processor]"] from JSON
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:43+00:00] INFO: Run List is [role[processor]]
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:43+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [opsworks_initial_setup, mysql::client, dependencies, opsworks_ganglia::client, deploy::default, ba-processor::setup, ba-processor::deploy, sidekiq::deploy, opsworks_ganglia::configure-client]
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:43+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for ubuntu1404-opsworks
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:43+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:43+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:43+00:00] WARN: found a directory vendor in the cookbook path, but it contains no cookbook files. skipping.
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:44+00:00] INFO: No db-master layer or MySQL RDS DB instance found. Skipping MySQL client package installation.
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:45+00:00] INFO: No monitoring-master node found. Skipping Ganglia client setup.
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:45+00:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for bash[restart_sidekiq] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:45+00:00] WARN: Previous bash[restart_sidekiq]: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-2/cookbooks/ba-processor/recipes/deploy.rb:54:in `from_file'
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:45+00:00] WARN: Current  bash[restart_sidekiq]: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-2/cookbooks/sidekiq/recipes/deploy.rb:30:in `block in from_file'
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:45+00:00] INFO: No monitoring-master node found. Skipping Ganglia client configuration.
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:45+00:00] INFO: execute[Setting sysctl: net.core.somaxconn] ran successfully
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:45+00:00] INFO: execute[Setting sysctl: net.core.netdev_max_backlog] ran successfully
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:45+00:00] INFO: execute[Setting sysctl: net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog] ran successfully
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:45+00:00] INFO: execute[Setting sysctl: net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout] ran successfully
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:45+00:00] INFO: execute[Setting sysctl: net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time] ran successfully
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:45+00:00] INFO: execute[Setting sysctl: net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans] ran successfully
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:45+00:00] INFO: execute[Setting sysctl: net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse] ran successfully
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:47+00:00] INFO: execute[Configure dynamic linker run-time bindings] ran successfully
==> default: sh: 1: 
==> default: /opt/aws/opsworks/current/cookbooks/../bin/downloader.sh: not found
==> default: 
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: Error executing action `install` on resource 'opsworks_commons_assets_installer[Install user space OpsWorks ruby package]'
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: Chef::Exceptions::ResourceNotFound
==> default: ----------------------------------
==> default: Failed to download asset opsworks-ruby2.1 for Install user space OpsWorks ruby package.
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: Cookbook Trace:
==> default: ---------------
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/opsworks_commons/providers/assets_installer.rb:85:in `local_asset'
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/opsworks_commons/providers/assets_installer.rb:5:in `block in class_from_file'
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: Resource Declaration:
==> default: ---------------------
==> default: # In /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/ruby/recipes/default.rb
==> default: 
==> default:  39:   opsworks_commons_assets_installer "Install user space OpsWorks ruby package" do
==> default:  40:     asset package_name
==> default:  41:     version node[:ruby][:version]
==> default:  42:     release node[:ruby][:pkgrelease]
==> default:  43: 
==> default:  44:     notifies :write, "log[downloading]", :immediately
==> default:  45:     action :install
==> default:  46:   end
==> default:  47: end
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: Compiled Resource:
==> default: ------------------
==> default: # Declared in /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/ruby/recipes/default.rb:39:in `from_file'
==> default: 
==> default: opsworks_commons_assets_installer("Install user space OpsWorks ruby package") do
==> default:   action [:install]
==> default:   retries 0
==> default:   retry_delay 2
==> default:   cookbook_name :ruby
==> default:   recipe_name "default"
==> default:   asset "opsworks-ruby2.1"
==> default:   version "2.1.5"
==> default:   release "1"
==> default:   max_fetch_retries 3
==> default: end
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:49+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:49+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:49+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:49+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:49+00:00] ERROR: opsworks_commons_assets_installer[Install user space OpsWorks ruby package] (ruby::default line 39) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::ResourceNotFound: Failed to download asset opsworks-ruby2.1 for Install user space OpsWorks ruby package.
==> default: [2015-01-07T04:35:49+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

I found this thread:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=154554

but is not very clear how he solve it, or if he solve the error.
I'm gonna be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The Opsworks cookbooks are not designed to be used locally. Many of them rely on node attributes that come from the Opsworks control system, which won't be present in your vagrant system and thus will come back blank. Please test this on Opsworks itself or complain to Amazon that their cookbooks are bad (or don't use them).

Comment: I think that I can do this because a colleague was able to run this locally and it works for him... so I think that I'm missing something here...

Comment: I did a trick here to have my vm working... after ":$ vagrant provision" I did ":$ vagrant ssh" then I did: :$ wget https://opsworks-instance-assets-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/packages/ubuntu/14.04/opsworks-ruby2.1_2.1.5- 1_amd64.deb and after that :$ dpkg -i https://opsworks-instance-assets-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/packages/ubuntu/14.04/opsworks-ruby2.1_2.1.5-1_amd64.deb I exit the Vm and the I ran again ":$ vagrant provision" and now is working.... but I still need to know who to fix the automatic installation of this package opsworks-ruby2.1_2.1.5-1_amd64.deb ....